# Show comments and parent comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, comments

I'm having trouble showing comments.
This is my table structure:

[image]

In my **ViewModel**:

```
// Comments
public ICollection<comments> Comments { get; set; }
// CommentText
public string _CommentText{ get; set; }
// CommentID
public int CommentID { get; set; }
// ParentCommentID
public int ParentCommentID { get; set; }
```

I would like to load a partial view '_comments.cshtml' where I show the comments and where you can add a comment. 
Does someone know how I start with this? I have no clue how I can show the comments.

I can get the comments through my repository like this:

```
//COMMENTS
public IQueryable<string> GetComments(int itemID)
{
    return from comment in entities.comments
           where comment.item_id.Equals(itemID)
           select comment.comment_text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check the `comment_parentid` field. if it is null or 0 then it should be parent comment of a particular item.